# Error While installing IBM Worklight Studio in Eclipse Java EE Indigo in Mac machine

Tags: eclipse, macos, ibm-mobilefirst

Please help me out . When i try to install IBM Worklight Studio in eclipse i get the following errors.

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.

Software being installed: IBM Worklight Studio 5.0.30.v20120808_2026 (com.ibm.imp.tools.feature.feature.group 5.0.30.v20120808_2026)

Missing requirement: Model Plug-in 7.0.400.v20120731_1538 (com.ibm.etools.webtools.model 7.0.400.v20120731_1538) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.emf.type.core [1.0.0,2.0.0)' but it could not be found

Cannot satisfy dependency:

From: Web Page Generation Core Plugin 7.2.300.v20120731_1538 (com.ibm.etools.webtools.webpage.core 7.2.300.v20120731_1538)

To: bundle com.ibm.etools.webtools.model [7.0.0,8.0.0)

Cannot satisfy dependency:

From: IBM Worklight Studio 5.0.30.v20120808_2026 (com.ibm.imp.tools.feature.feature.group 5.0.30.v20120808_2026)

To: com.ibm.wdt.webtools.ajax.feature.feature.group 1.0.0

Cannot satisfy dependency:

From: AJAX Web Tools 1.0.0.v20120731_1538 (com.ibm.wdt.webtools.ajax.feature.feature.group 1.0.0.v20120731_1538)

To: com.ibm.etools.webtools.webpage.core _http://7.2.300.v20120731_1538
```

Answer (score 2):

Is the checkbox "Contact all update sites during install to find required" checked? Are you connected to the internet?

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think WTP plugin is yet properly installed in your eclipse, remove the plugin and try to install the latest WTP plugin. Are you using Helios or Indigo release 2 version.  Try to update the eclipse and reinstall the Worklight